# List all files on MacOS

Tags: macos, go, directory, macos-catalina

I have created a program in Go to list all files in my Mac larger than a certain size.

```
..........
const dir string = "/"
..........
func main() {

    err := filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
..........
```

The program finds files like

- /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.Xcode.bom
- /private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.Xcode.bom
- /Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Proofing Tools/FinnishGrammar.proofingtool/Contents/SharedSupport/FinnishGrammar.lexicon/Contents/Resources/DataFile.lex
- /System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Proofing Tools/FinnishGrammar.proofingtool/Contents/SharedSupport/FinnishGrammar.lexicon/Contents/Resources/DataFile.lex

so it duplicates every file. I could eliminate the duplicates in the program but I would prefer not to list them in the first place. I used as path "**/**" to get all the files. Is there something else I should use?

Comment: It looks like your `/System/Volumes/Data` mount point mounts the same disk or disk-image as your file system root. That's not something I've seen in MacOS, and I'm not sure how you got into that state...

Comment: I upgraded to macOS Catalina from Sierra or El Capitan. I don't know how this state was before.